# Faster way to expand submenus using keyboard

Tags: keyboard, macos

Consider the nested menus structure (from Intellij) as shown in the screenshot:
[image]

Using the `right arrow` key will cause the `Find` submenu to expand. But the right arrow key is inconvenient/slow to reach.

In Linux/Windows the Menu actually opens automatically: is there some faster key combination  - than the awkward `^F2-<E>-<F>-<Right Arrow Key>` way to nudge OS/X to "move along" a bit faster?

Note: Intellij has ***over 150 menu items*** so comments/answers like "Why not use Hotkeys?" are naive/impractical.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I think it's done this way, because you can type the name of the command using the keyboard, and by pressing the `→` you also move "the keyboard focus" to the submenu. P.S. it's just my guess..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use hotkeys from that menu? `⌘F`, `⌘R` etc.

Use `Control + ]`

Comment: How many `hotkeys` do you want me to remember?? There are ***14 top level menu items*** in Intellij - each of which has between ***15 to 25 subentries*** - some of which are actually submenus ..  so maybe .. ***200 or so menu items ?***   And some of them change from one version of Intellij to the next. This is *not* like `command-c` for copy  - which I *do* use: there are only maybe 15 of those kinds of standard editing shortcuts to remember.

Comment: Use control + ]

Comment: `control-]` works!  How did you discover it?  Are there other similar "tricks"?

Comment: I just tried all combinations with control ;-)